# How can I run tasks on multi process using WorkManager?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

### Background

My application has two process. One(**main process**) is generally handling UI related jobs. And the other one(**remote process**) is taking care various types of jobs. Both processes have different tasks, resources and roles. So, each process can run their scheduled job on their own context. Also, every jobs SHALL run on their scoped process.

### Problem

BTW, I tried to schedule a job using `WorkManager`(v2.1.0) on the **remote process**, but it was triggered on the **main process**. Because `WorkManager` register jobs to `SystemJobService`, and its target process is **main**.

I tried to configure the target `Service`, but I couldn't. How can I configure it?

Comment: See my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845895/android-workmanager-run-job-in-a-fixed-process/65446768#65446768